# Setting pkcs11 cfg file

Tags: java, pkcs#11

I am trying to run an example of how to use pkcs11 using the next code

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class SignWithPKCS11
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
            try
            {
                    Class<?> pkcs11Class = Class.forName("sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11");
                    Constructor<?> construct = pkcs11Class.getConstructor(new Class[] {String.class});

                    String configName = "pkcs11.cfg";
                    Provider p = (Provider)construct.newInstance(new Object[] {configName});
                    Security.addProvider(p);
            }
            catch (Throwable t)
            {
                    t.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
```

The code above, calls the file pkcs11.cfg. The content of it is

```
name = JSignPdf
library = /home/grados-sanchez/grive/E-CONNECTING/david/opensc-pkcs11.so
```

using this command

```
java -cp . SignWithPKCS11
java -Djava.library.path=".:/home/grados-sanchez/grive/E-CONNECTING/david" -cp . SignWithPKCS11
```

but I get

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at SignWithPKCS11.main(SignWithPKCS11.java:32)
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:376)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:103)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: libopensc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory/home/grados-sanchez/grive/E-CONNECTING/david/opensc-pkcs11.so
```

Could you help me, to fix it, please? What is wrong?

NOTE: When I did:

```
 ls -l /home/grados-sanchez/grive/E-CONNECTING/david/opensc-pkcs11.so
```

I get

```
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 220232 Jun 19 01:59 /home/grados-sanchez/grive/E-CONNECTING/david/opensc-pkcs11.so
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using reflection, instead of the classes directly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's not the `opensc-pkcs11.so` that is missing, but a dependency of that library. Use `ldd` to check those dependencies. If they reside in the same directory as the provider, you need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/grados-sanchez/grive/E-CONNECTING/david` before executing the command (as a prefix, for example).